# How to handle save of complex object in service layer

Tags: java, architecture, clean-architecture

I have a complex object domain object call A. Which is composed of 3 other objects.

```
public class A { 
  private B bObject;
  private C cObject;
  private D dObject;

  //somes primitive types fields
}
```

I had a service layer for the object A.

```
public class serviceA {
  private RepositoryA repositoryForA;

  //CRUD operations on A
}
```

Object B,C,D have their own repository and they do not have service layer. Because they dont have buisness logic for the moment. They just contain informations for A.

For save A I need to save all the composed object B,C,D and I have to inject B,C,D repository into serviceA class.

So I dont think is a good idea, for each new composed object on A I will need to inject a new repository on serviceA class.
Are my A object is to complex, or is has to be done this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Java context and I use JPA/Hibernate. So if I use the good relation between the objet Hibernate should save all the composite object.

https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy question. Anyway, I make it simple and I also suppose there's a relationship between A and B, C and D. So I expect saving A doesn't really mean anything without saving the objects composing it, in this case the service layer of A should care also about his children.